# Kubuntu 15.04 black bar at the bottom of the screen covering panel

Tags: kubuntu, 15.04, kde, display-resolution

I recently installed Kubuntu 15.04, and after a programm I ran in wine changed my resolution, I've had a black bar at the bottom obscuring my activity panel. I can still click on everything and it shows the Icon when hovering over the bar, but I can't see anything. I also have the same problem in fullscreen games or videos.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y1Wka.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ps4eM.jpg

I have already deleted the .config folder, deleted the .kde folder, deleted plasma and also reinstalled kubuntu-full from aptitude. None of these things has fixed this. Any help would be appreciated with this.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was to delete this file: `~/.local/share/kscreen`

My process to find this was to create a new user and log in with that. I had made sure the same symptoms weren't being displayed (the desktop was fine). I then began the arduous task of copying directories/files from the affected user to this new user (logging in and out between the two users) until the black bar would appear. Once I found the offending file, I removed it from the affected account and logged in. No more black bar.